# Hashmaps - using booleans

Tags: java, hashmap

I was implementing a Java program containing hash maps, I wanted to use two different hash-maps and a boolean function. So for every key, depending on the boolean outcome, it would select one of the hash-maps. What would be some disadvantages/advantage of this?

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  You could have a single map like `Map<Boolean, Map<SomeKey, SomeValue>>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this (as far as I can think of at the moment):

**Method 1:** (from @WJS in the comments)

Have a HashMap with a boolean key and the corresponding HashMap as the value. Like so:

```
HashMap<Boolean, Map<Key, Value>> outer = new HashMap<>();
```

**Method 2:**
Since there can only be two HashMaps corresponding to your boolean ***true*** or ***false*** value, I don't think you need to have another HashMap and can simply use a boolean variable.

For Example:

```
// or similar depending on your implementation and needs; can be 
// extended for choosing get(), set(), etc.

boolean flag;
HashMap<Key, Value> trueMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Key, Value> falseMap = new HashMap<>();

HashMap<Key, Value> map = flag ? trueMap : falseMap;
```

There is no downside to having HashMaps chosen like this and is actually fairly common.